# How to fix Error in installing "react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I got error while installing the react-router-dom.
[image: error pictur]

```sh
D:\react\routeingreact>npm i react-router-dom
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\5442\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-01T05_06_17_337Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Please post errors as plain text and not screen shots. Where is "Cannot read property 'match' of undefined" in the error?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. The error message points to a log, you want to include that too for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to install the wrong package. There is no package `router-react-dom`. You are looking for [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom). You mixed up the order of the words `react` and `router` in your install command. The correct install command would be:

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

I'd recommend reviewing the [getting started guide](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) for `react-router-dom` also.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: D:\react\routeingreact>npm i react-router-dom
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\5442\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-01T05_06_17_337Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete one file and one directory:

- package-lock.json
- node_modules

That should you get you back on track